# Is it good to make api call made in try-catch block or outside, in redux-saga?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, redux-saga

I have a following function in my saga.ts file :

```
export function* getProductsList(action) {
   yield put(productsListAttempt(true));

   const productsList = yield api.getProductsList();

   try {

     yield put(productsListSuccess(productsList));

   } catch {

     yield put(productsListError('Error occured'));
   }
}
```

I am trying to write a unit test for this function. The problem I am encountering with this is, whenever I execute my test for FAILURE of the function it does not pass well. It never gives result as per the catch block. But when I put this line: `const productsList = yield api.getProductsList();` in the try block then the test pass as per expectation.

-- Is it really good to put api call outside try block or not? Why so ?

Comment: In many of the tutorials which I referred to learn Redux-saga, the api call was in the Try block. But at my work, my seniors has put it outside the try-catch block

Comment: Not sure why you are not sure. Better to put it in the `try` so you can test it but more importantly so you can react in the real usage scenario.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli other than the unit test scenarios, it does not cause any problem.

Comment: perhaps there is global error handling in the app and so they do not want the error handled locally.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli when it make a call to the function productsListError('Error occurred'), they set this string message to the state in reducer and then show it on the view. Other than that there is no error handling logic.

Comment: I think you should put this in the try block, if your api call function raise an error or does not handle a promise rejection is always better to put in a try statements, if you want go in a more 'functional' way, if your function returns a promise you could alway use a then/catch statement, it's totally up to you.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong putting the call inside a try/catch block, I do the same in my projects and it's fine because the call can fail and the try/catch let you, by definition, manage this error case